# Auto Scaling in aws Using the Command Line Interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

i am new to auto scaling , i want to know the commands to create a group and how we attach to my ec2 instance .

i have tried number of command on aws web site but it is not working :

as-create-launch-config my-test-lc --image-id ami-0078da69 --instance-type m1.small

as-create-auto-scaling-group my-test-asg --launch-configuration my-test-lc --availability-zones us-east-1a --min-size 1 --max-size 10 --desired-capacity 1

Comment: and when i run the command on cli mode it is showing me :C:\Users\nikunj>as-create-auto-scaling-group test-1 --launch-configuration test-1a --availability-zones us-east-1a --min-size 0 --max-size 1
as-create-auto-scaling-group:  Malformed input-File not found: C:\Users\nikunj\Downloads\RDS

Comment: i have done with the last problem but now i am stuck other command :not able to create scaling made command what i am using is :           as-create-auto-scaling-group test-1a --launch-configuration test-1a --availability-zones us-east-1 --min-size 0 --max-size 1 --desired-capacity 1   and it is showing me the error : as-create-auto-scaling-group:  Malformed input-Launch configuration name not found - A launch configuration
 with the name : test-1a does not exist